# Reading Databricks tables in Azure

Tags: azure-databricks, delta-lake

Please clarify my confusion as I keep hearing we need read every Parquet file created by Databricks Delta tables to get to latest data in case of a SCD2 table. Is this true?

Can we simply use SQL and get the latest row?
Can we use some date/time columns to get to history of changes to that row?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and manage a Delta table as SCD2 if you wish. Actually, what confuses you must be the [Time Travel](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html#deltatimetravel) feature.  It just allow you to rollback your Delta table to any of its historical states which are automatically managed by Databricks.

**Answer:**

- No. Instead, we need to look into all Delta lake transaction logs which are stored as JSON files inside _delta_log folder along with Parquet files and then see which parquet files are used as the latest data.  See this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/delta-resources) for more information.
- Yes. We can use SQL to get the latest row.  Actually, any SQL script execution will always return latest data.  However, there are 2 ways to get historical version of the table by SQL which are 1) specifying "as of version" and 2) specifying "as of timestamp".  Read [more](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html#deltatimetravel).

PS This is a really good question.